# How many people have 501 certification?

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, certification

Any idea how many people have their Advanced developer certification worldwide/domestically? Is it closer to 1000? 10,000?  Just wanted to get some statistics on that..

Comment: Not sure but this is definately must for apex and visualforce programmers .

Comment: Unfortunately Salesforce doesn't publish these numbers, although it never hurts to email certification@salesforce.com and see if they'll give you a ballpark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [listings page](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/results?type=Developer&filter=sk=AandV) at Salesforce shows a thousand people. Some simple statistics on names could give a rough estimate. However, many people probably choose not to be on there and it's not listed by certificates.

Comment: I don't think you have to have a 501 cert to be listed there (but I could be wrong).

Comment: Yes, anyone who has a login to the success community can add their name and state that they have "Apex / VF skills"